# Storing JSON Data as a String Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

So i have gotten my Json data in which i have got:

```
{
"name": "brad"
}
```

I am trying to store that individual name as a string.

```
@try
{
     NSError *error;
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://Share/scripts/newjson.json"];
///Dummy URL
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"json: %@", json);

}
@catch (NSException *e)
{
    NSLog(@"Internet not enabled");
    //something went wrong
    //populate the NSError object so it can be accessed
}
```

But when i print out the json file i just get what is shown above, do i need to use a delimiter or something to get this string ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually the JSON is a dictionary not an array and with `nilOptions` not mutable.

To get *brad* write

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSString *name = json[@"name"];
NSLog(@"name: %@", name);
```